# VueJs - mutation not save new object to state

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have a problem with update my vuex store after update my user credentials in one of the component, here is my code:

```
 mutations: {
    updateUserState: function(state, user) {
      state.user = user;
    },
}

actions: {
    updateUserData({ commit }, user) {
      commit("updateUserState", user);
    },
}
```

in component:

```
    updateUserData() {
      //function to update data in db
      UserService.updateUserData(this.firstName, this.lastName).then(res => {
        if(res.code == 200) {
          this.makeToast('success', res.message);
          //function to get current user data after update
          UserService.getUserData().then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            //update my store -> NOT WORK
            this.$store.dispatch("auth/updateUserData", res.data);
          })
        } else {
          this.makeToast('error', res.message);
        }
      })
    }
```

when i on submit launch `updateUserData` function my state is updated on this same page (I have a navbar with data from `this.$store.state.auth.user;`) instant after this action but when i change my page then i have my old data from state (before update in previous page) ... :(

can someone tell me what is wrong here?
thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

How do you access your user instance in your Navbar component?
You need to make it reactive in order to update its value so the best practice is to define a getter in your store file for example in `auth.js` module:

```
getters: {
    user(state) {
        return state.user;
    },
}
```

and put it in the computed property of the navbar component like this:

```
<script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

    export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['auth/user'])
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: how to put in span an data from this mapGetters?

Comment: @markWanka You can access values in `computed` the same way you access a value in `data` by using double curly notation like `{{ user.name }}`

Comment: hmmm, that not work, still change me data in state to old values :/

Comment: Show me how you get user data in navbar